# how to load map marker automatically when page loaded in ionic 2?

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

in Ionic2 I use the fallowing code to load marker when page loaded but it shows error:

```
initializeMap() {

let minZoomLevel = 16;
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
zoom: minZoomLevel,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
mapTypeControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
disableDefaultUI: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
  });
Marker(){  
  let source = "origin";
   let image = 'assets/img/Untitled-1.png';   
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter(),
    draggable: true
    , icon: image
  }); 
  this.lastLatLng(marker,source);
}
```

in this code I call `marker()` by

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.Marker();
}
```

> view-controller.js:471 MapPage ionViewDidEnter error: Cannot read
>   property 'getCenter' of null

**Update 1:** screenshot  after @Rohit-kumar-vinay request:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that i had to do is that call `this.Marker();` at the end of   `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function. many thanks to **Josh Morony**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnInit` from `@angular/core`

1. Import `OnInint`

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
   ```
2. Implement in export class

   ```
   export class WelcomePage implements OnInit {
     map:any
   }
   ```
3. Implement function

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
     this.map = this.initMap();
   }

   initMap(): Promise<void> {
   let promise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

   let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
   let GooleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: latLng,
     zoom: 18
   });
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latLng,
     map: GooleMap,
     title: 'My Location',
   });
   });
   });
   return promise;
   }
   ```

follow below links for uber app clone using ionic2
[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIQQPtwzejqVguZj5DYrO1w0QbNSJWmT-) / 
[Github Link](https://github.com/doorty/Ionic-2-Uber)

Comment: tnx, but it shows error for 'loadingCtrl' and 'this.map = this.initMap();'

Comment: I've got that but still there is an error with this line: `this.map = this.initMap();` and type promise <void>is not assignable .

Comment: can u send console screenshot?

Comment: @Reza have made changes to answer, i have imported `Geolocation` and set `map:any;` inside export

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136993/discussion-between-reza-and-rohit-kumar-vinay).

Comment: could you please check this: `https://plnkr.co/edit/reJB9SouI6Uus6nLHaKs?p=catalogue` I've uploaded map.html map.ts map.scss in this acount