# How to put segments in toolbar inline with different colors in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

in this code i try to add `segment buttons` in line but they are underline

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="icons" color="secondary">
      <ion-segment-button value="camera">
        <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
        </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="icons" color="danger">
      <ion-segment-button value="bookmark" >
        <ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>    
    </ion-navbar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `ion-segment` element inside another `ion-segment` element. Please try with something like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>App Name</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="icons">
            <ion-segment-button value="camera">
                <ion-icon color="primary" name="camera"></ion-icon>
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="bookmark">
                <ion-icon color="secondary" name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Like you can see in the code above, I'm setting the color in each icon `<ion-icon color="primary" name="camera"></ion-icon>` and `<ion-icon color="secondary" name="bookmark"></ion-icon>`

---

**UPDATE:**

Just like you can see in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/segment/Segment/) if you want to bind a method to each button, instead of using the click event, you can use `(ionSelect)="yourMethod(...)"` in the `ion-segment-button` like this:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="relationship" color="primary">
  <ion-segment-button value="friends" (ionSelect)="selectedFriends()">
    Friends
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="enemies" (ionSelect)="selectedEnemies()">
    Enemies
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras, thank you so much. I think it will working fine but if I would like add a method to each button should be like `<ion-segment-button (click)="takephoto()" value="camera">`, isn't it?

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've updated the answer to show you how to bind a method to each segment button. You should use the `ionSelect` event instead of the `click` event

Comment: Hey @sebaferreras, if it was possible I will press answer acceptance for second time. tnx so much saved me so much of time :))

Comment: That's great... please let me know if I can help you with anything else, that's what we're here for :)

Comment: could you please check these question also they are so important for me: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655227/how-to-implementing-direction-to-delivery-service-project-in-ionic-2) , [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515474/how-to-load-map-marker-automatically-when-page-loaded-in-ionic-2) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621301/how-to-make-a-responsive-canvas-for-google-map-in-ionic-2) ,these are not answered and I couldn't solve them by lack of my knowledge and experiences.